# How to make Flexbox Gallery Images with Links attached to them making them the flex childs

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I'm trying to make imgaes with links inside flexbox. The problem is, when i add the `<a href="">`, the imgages no longer becomes the flex items of the .gallery class.

I cant figure out, it's there a way to make the images to remain child of the container having links on them? I want the images be flex-items and be clickable with links.

```css
.Portfolio {
  display: flex;
  background-color: ;
  width: 80%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  background-color: orange;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
  <div class="Portfolio">
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="zoom" src="01.jpg" width="30%" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show your css - use the snippet button to create a [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I've find the "solution" using unordered list `<ul>` with lists `<li>`of images `<img src="#">` and enveloped with `<a>` tag. `<ul>` becomes flex container and `<li>` becomes flex items! Could be also ordered list.

```css
*{
  list-style: none;
}


ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


img:hover{
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/01.png" width="300" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/02.png" width="300" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/03.png" width="300" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/04.png" width="300" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/05.png" width="300" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="img/06.png" width="300" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>
```